# wxPython TreeCtrl very slow with millions of nodes (on multi-select tree control)

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I am creating a tree with millions of nodes, but when I switched to using multiple-select on a tree control (wx.TR_MULTIPLE), actions on tree become slower, I only click to select a node and it takes me a few seconds. This does not happen when I use the single-select style (wx.TR_SINGLE).

I have tried to not set data for any node and did not use any event but it still slow.
Is there any way to use multiple-select on a tree control and the tree still fast as single-select?

I've pasted the modified demo code in below:

```py
import wx


class MyTree(wx.TreeCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, pos, size, style):
        wx.TreeCtrl.__init__(self, parent, id, pos, size, style)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED, self.item_changed)

    def item_changed(self, evt):
        print(self.GetItemData(evt.GetItem()))


class TreePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.tree = MyTree(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TR_HAS_BUTTONS | wx.TR_MULTIPLE)
        self.root = self.tree.AddRoot('ROOT')
        node1 = self.tree.InsertItem(self.root, 0, 'Node 1', data='node 1')
        for i in range(1000000):
            self.tree.PrependItem(node1, 'Sub node 1: ' + str(i), data='Sub node 1: ' + str(i))
        self.tree.Expand(self.root)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.tree, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title='TreeCtrl Demo')
        panel = TreePanel(self)
        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Are you talking about expanding a node or individual selection of an item in an already expanded node and what OS?  p.s. Are you really using `PrependItem` on such a vast tree, that will be multitudes slower than `AppendItem`.

Comment: It's about the individual selection of an item in an already expanded node and I am testing it on my windows 10. One thing is that I really do not know why `PrependItem` is faster than `AppendItem`. It takes me a few seconds to add the whole node using `PrependItem` (or just `InsertItem` at 0-index). If I use `AppendItem` it takes a very long time. Thanks!

Comment: You may have to wait for answer from a windows user then. On Linux there appears to be no such issue and AppendItem for 100,000 items is 6 times quicker, for 1,000,000 it is 60 times quicker. Clearly, there is a fundamental difference in the under-lying code.

Comment: There is a difference in the underlying implementation. On Windows, wxWidgets wraps the native tree control. On Linux, it uses the generic implementation. WxPython has a generic implementation of wx.TreeCtrl for all platforms under wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl which is an exact port of the C++ code. However, being Python and the notorious and ridiculous aversion of Python for all kind of loops, I don’t expect CustomTreeCtrl to be very performant.

Comment: Beside what I said above, and as I said on the wxPython bug tracker, you should rethink your presentation mode - a tree with one parent and a million children is not a good design choice. How about a virtual wx.ListCtrl? Or a virtual wx.grid.Grid?

Comment: I have ever thought about that, but it seems like my customer did not want to change their user behavior. They have the same app which was written by another language, and it is able to render millions of children under one parent (still fast). We have a lot of nodes (with many levels), one of them maybe have millions of children, that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I also have the same problems. But when I change to the single choice it becomes fast again, but at this time we can not choose multiple node... hmmm.
I think this related with C-code inside the framework